# Reference Request: Control Theory Prerequisites for Quantitative Finance

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-control

Right now, even though I have a mathematical background, I did not take up control theory in college. I'm looking for an introductory text on (stochastic?) control theory as applicable to quantitative finance.

I did look up control theory textbooks on amazon but they're explicitly for electrical engineering, and I have no idea which topics covered in those books are not used at all in finance (e.g., Optimal Control Theory: An Introduction by Kirk).

If they are no books specifically for control theory in finance, could anyone give me a comprehensive list of topics to cover so that I can cover the mathematical prerequisites for portfolio management/financial engineering? Thanks

Comment: Control theory books are of 2 kinds: the purely theoretical, and the more engineering oriented. I believe any of the latter kind are suitable for Finance, there were none specifically oriented to finance when I studied it and I don't think there are any now (as yet). The topics of interest are the typical ones: state space systems, LQG, Pontryagin, Kalman, etc. The basic stuff.

Comment: I also studied a book Optimal Control Theory: Applications to Management Science and Economics, By Suresh P. Sethi, Gerald L. Thompson. But keep in mind that it is not at all about Finance.

Comment: I did not come across a real control theory application in my career so far. There is the field of dynamic programming however, where I would say both optimization as well as programming kind of take over. For a real mathematical stochastic control theory book you probably need to be a mathematician and I dont say that lightly.

Comment: @AlexC: You mentioned the topics of interest. Could you give a full list of all such topics (to your knowledge)? That way I can just look them up online or find control theory books that address these topics. I did find a textbook reference in a related answer : https://www.amazon.com/dp/3642100449. Do you think this book would be useful, or is it too theoretical?

Comment: @AlexC: Another one is this: https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Controls-Hamiltonian-Equations-Probability/dp/0387987231/. Again, I want to have an idea whether this book indeed covers the desired topics or foundation.

Comment: I have not read either of the books you mentioned, but they seem quite difficult, specially the second one. You might start with something much simpler, such as the Kirk, or something addressed to Electrical or Aeronautical engineers as the audience, not mathematicians.